# quotient of direct sum of modules is the direct sum of the quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, quotient-group

I am making a proof and at a certain point I need to use the following, but I am not sure that it is true:

Let $M=M_1\oplus M_2$ be a module over a $K$-algebra $A$, with $M_1,M_2\leq M$. If $N\le M$, then $$\frac{M}{N} \simeq \frac{M_1}{N\cap M_1}\oplus \frac{M_2}{N\cap M_2}.$$

I tried to prove it in a natural way, but I'm missing the last part:

I consider the obvious map $$\phi: m = m_1 + m_2\in M \mapsto (m_1+N\cap M_2, m_2 + N\cap M_2).$$

This map is onto because if I take a pair $(m_1 + N\cap M_1, m_2 + N\cap M_2)$ then it suffices to take $m = m_1 + m_2$ as a pre-image.

As regards the kernel, we have that $m=m_1 + m_2\in Ker\phi \Rightarrow m_1\in N, m_2\in N \Rightarrow m\in N$.

I'm not sure that this holds because I'm not able to prove the converse: if $m= m_1 + m_2 \in N$, how can I prove that both the component are in $N$? It does not seem true, or at least I can not see any reason why it should be.

In case it is not true, what can I say, in general, about the quotient of an internal direct sum?

Thanks everybody in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Consider a field $K$, and the vector space $M=K\oplus K$
and take $N=\{(a,a):a\in K\}$. Then $N\cap M_j=0$ for $j=1$, $2$.

Comment: Ok, I suspected that. Thank you.

And do you know whether there is something general that we can say with respect to the quotient of an internal direct sum like that in my question or not?